# Load Assembly with custom Permissions

Tags: .net, code-access-security

I need to load an untrusted assembly into my AppDomain. I don't want to Sandbox a new AppDomain for this assembly to execute in, because it internally requires access to certain functionality such as HttpContext.Current (which would be null in a separate sandboxed AppDomain).

I think the old way of doing this would have been calling Assembly.Load with some custom Evidence, but it looks like this has been made obsolete by the CAS changes in 4.0:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145229.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191568(VS.100).aspx

I don't quite understand how I can accomplish what I want here with the new security model... Could someone please explain or suggest an alternative approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is an immense mouthful...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984947.aspx

But I finally found what I was looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostsecuritypolicyresolver.aspx

Just took a long long time to find...

Answer (score 0):

You can revert to the legacy model by modifying your applications configuration, the second link contains a reference right at the top but see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409253.aspx) for more info. Then you can just used mixed trust assemblies in the default appdomain.

Comment: I saw that, and I'll consider doing it, but if there's a way of doing this with the new security model, I'd like to do so.